# gs ghost script cannot adjust pdf size - either adjust to ~28MB or either to 128MB

Tags: pdf, compression

I am trying to reduce pdf filesize. It has an original size of ~130mb
I succceeded to use 72 or 96 DPI to reduce filesize <30MB.
BUT it is a big different from ~130 to goes to ~30MB.
I want something like ~60-50MB.
But i dont know how to do that.

I have seen pdfs with much higher DPI (eg. 120) and 1/10 of mine resolution.
So their size is ~30-50Mb.
My pdf file is only images taken by phone.

[example files for 7 days](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f832ea3ba830c5285ecbdeeb72ae644a20220711213816/334cd2)

```
RES=150; THRES=1.0; SUBS=/Bicubic
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH  -dSubsetFonts=true -dCompressFonts=true -dCompressMode=2 -dCompressEntireFile=true \
-sProcessColorModel=DeviceRGB  -sColorConversionStrategy=sRGB  -sColorConversionStrategyForImages=sRGB \
-dDownsampleColorImages=true           -dDownsampleGrayImages=true                    -dDownsampleMonoImages=true \
  -dColorImageResolution=$RES           -dGrayImageResolution=$RES                     -dMonoImageResolution=$RES \
   -dColorImageDownsampleType=$SUBS  -dGrayImageDownsampleType=$SUBS           -dMonoImageDownsampleType=$SUBS      \
    -dColorImageDownsampleThreshold=$THRES -dGrayImageDownsampleThreshold=$THRES          -dMonoImageDownsampleThreshold=$THRES \
    -dDoThumbnails=false  -dCreateJobTicket=false  -dPreserveEPSInfo=false  -dPreserveOPIComments=false   -dPreserveOverprintSettings=false  -dUCRandBGInfo=/Remove \
    -dAutoFilterColorImage=false \
    -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook \
    -sOutputFile="/mnt/Basic_HDD/COPIES/SCANS/prx/150.pdf" \
    -c '<</ColorACSImageDict << /Blend 1 /HSamples [1 1 1 1] /VSamples [1 1 1 1] /QFactor 0.08 /ColorTransform 1 >>  \
       <</GrayACSImageDict << /Blend 1 /HSamples [1 1 1 1] /VSamples [1 1 1 1] /QFactor 0.08 /ColorTransform 1 >> setdistillerparams' \
    -f "/mnt/Basic_HDD/COPIES/SCANS/prx/orig.pdf"
```

mine (size 130MB)

```
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
  1     0 image    3072  4096  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        79  0    96    96 4713K  13%
```

others (size 11-20MB).

```
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
    1     0 image    1024  1490  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no         1  0   128   128  397K 8.9%
```

Comment: what options did you used to make that size using GS (Ghostscript) ?

Answer (score 0):

GhostScript is not designed as a PDF compressor, however as a result of downgrading some jpg values can produce smaller less accurate files with slightly acceptable visual lossy settings.

You asked which options produced a result close to your desired value and these are the setting as used by an online gui compressor, so I cant vouch for their use in all cases. I used resolution 144 as a reasonable choice, but that is not the only factor, it is QFactor that will cause the visual Quality change

```
cmdline=
-dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="output.pdf" -dAutoRotatePages=/None \
-dEmbedAllFonts=true -dSubsetFonts=true -dDetectDuplicateImages=true -dDoThumbnails=false \
-dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dAutoFilterMonoImages=false \
-r144 -dColorImageResolution=144 -dGrayImageResolution=144 -dMonoImageResolution=144 \
-dDownsampleColorImages=true -dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dColorImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0 \
-dDownsampleGrayImages=true -dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dGrayImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0 \
-dDownsampleMonoImages=true -dMonoImageDownsampleType=/Subsample -dMonoImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0 \
-dColorConversionStrategy=/sRGB -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceRGB -dPassThroughJPEGImages=false \
-dColorImageFilter=/DCTEncode -dGrayImageFilter=/DCTEncode -dMonoImageFilter=/CCITTFaxEncode \
-c " <</ColorImageDict  <</QFactor 0.24 /Blend 1 /ColorTransform 1 /HSample [1 1 1 1] /VSample [1 1 1 1]>> >> setdistillerparams <</GrayImageDict  <</QFactor 0.24 /Blend 1 /ColorTransform 1 /HSample [1 1 1 1] /VSample [1 1 1 1]>> >> setdistillerparams" \
-f "input.pdf"
```

Comment: Do you know a program designed for pdf -image compressor? Cause i though GS was made for that reason (to compress pdf)...